# Create Application Insights Alerts for all Resources

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager

Is there an easy way to add the same alerts to all resources withing Application Insights?

I'd like to create a server exception count/threshold alert, but don;t want to manually update 20+ AI resources.

Also, as rules and needs change it would be nice to be able to do something. I think ARM might provide a way to pull in the resources and then iterate over each of them creating the alerts. Any other ideas? Or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Azure Power Shell or Template to do this.

For template: You could check this [template](https://github.com/janusznowak/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/feature/301-insights-alertrules-application-insights/301-insights-alertrules-application-insights/azuredeploy.json).

```
{
      "name": "[variables('responseAlertName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertrules",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsName'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('appInsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[variables('responseAlertName')]",
        "description": "response time alert",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "condition": {
          "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', variables('appInsName'))]",
            "metricName": "request.duration"
          },
          "threshold": "[parameters('responseTime')]",
          "windowSize": "PT5M"
        },
        "actions": [
          {
            "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleEmailAction, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
            "sendToServiceOwners": true,
            "customEmails": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

You also could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-powershell#add-a-metric-alert).

For PowerShell, you could use command [`Add-AzureRmLogAlertRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.insights/add-azurermmetricalertrule?view=azurermps-5.3.0). For example:

```
Add-AzureRmLogAlertRule -Name "logRule" -Location "East US" -ResourceGroup "Default-Web-EastUS" -OperationName "Create" -TargetResourceId "/subscriptions/abbfb07c-6c93-40be-bc9b-4f0deba32f4c/resourceGroups/Default-Web-EastUS/providers/microsoft.web/sites/misitiooeltuyo" -Description "My log rule"
```

Comment: You also could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-powershell-alerts), but the powershell is classic  cmdlet, you need replace it to `Add-AzureRmLogAlertRule`.